# Java: Recursive Thread Creation for a Thread Pool -> How to detect completion

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I'm working on a program to play TicTac toe.

It will use a game tree search. However, first I need to assemble the game tree.

I want to parallelize this process, since it basically involves checking the current position, generating all the legal moves, and attaching these as nodes to the current node.

This is my first real foray into multithreading, and I keep running into problems.

Here is my move generation code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { // try all cells
            if (isMoveLegal(i)) {
                Node newnode = new Node(currentNode,
                        Game.convertMoveToBin(i - 1));
                currentNode.addChild(newnode);
                if (Game.evaluateBoards(newnode.getBoards()) == 2) {
                    executor.submit(new MoveGenerationThread(currentNode,
                            newnode));
                }
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
 }}
```

I have a static thread pool executor:

```
public static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);
```

I tried using transient thread pools, but the program went beserk and ran out of threads.

Basically, what is happening is that a task is being run in the thread pool, and then each task is generating more tasks to run in separate threads.

The problem is knowing when everything finishes. I am not just running a simple loop where I can wait till the tasks are done, this is being done recursively. I've tried various methods of detecting completion including a CountDownLatch (doesn't work, I don't know how many tasks there are going to be), wait() (crashes, doesn't seem to be applicable to this situation), and shutdown(), which doesn't work either (I don't want to stop more tasks from being submitted).

I am a bit bewildered here, any ideas?

I think the answer might have something to do with Fork/Join, but I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Uhm, have you considered using `Future`s?

Comment: Yes, but then I have to be repeatedly looping through those values while I am adding new ones. Would you suggest a static ArrayList of Futures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `java.util.concurrent.Phaser`.

Use `register()` to increment the count as each task is created.  At the end of each task, call `arriveAndDeregister()`.

Comment: That works great. I just made that a static member of my class and called a shutdown when it went back down to 0. Thanks!